# Why am I getting this error from having nonvalid unicode in source (But only when importing matplotlib)

Tags: python-3.x, pyparsing

So it took me a while before I pinned the cause of this one but still am at loss off how it is possible. I have recently switched to python3 and I got this huge error when trying to import matplotlib:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/y2kbugger/Desktop/test.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\mypackage\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", lin
e 124, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\mypackage\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line
 30, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\mypackage\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\fontconfig_patter
n.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pyparsing import Literal, ZeroOrMore, \
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\mypackage\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 3539, in
 <module>
    _escapedPunc = Word( _bslash, r"\[]-*.$+^?()~ ", exact=2 ).setParseAction(la
mbda s,l,t:t[0][1])
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\mypackage\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 966, in
setParseAction
    self.parseAction = list(map(_trim_arity, list(fns)))
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\mypackage\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 813, in
_trim_arity
    this_line = extract_stack()[-1]
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\mypackage\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 797, in
extract_stack
    frame_summary = traceback.extract_stack()[offset]
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\mypackage\lib\traceback.py", line 207, in extract_stack
    stack = StackSummary.extract(walk_stack(f), limit=limit)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\mypackage\lib\traceback.py", line 358, in extract
    f.line
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\mypackage\lib\traceback.py", line 282, in line
    self._line = linecache.getline(self.filename, self.lineno).strip()
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\mypackage\lib\linecache.py", line 16, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\mypackage\lib\linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\mypackage\lib\linecache.py", line 137, in updatecache
    lines = fp.readlines()
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\mypackage\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 308: invali
d start byte
```

Commenting out the `import matplotlib as mpl` causes the error not to occur. This led me astray trying different combinations of matplot, numpy, etc. The part that confuses me is that if I delete the comments (that I pasted from the web) the error is actually fixed. My editor is vim. I guess utf-8 was not the encoding that vim used to write the file.

Minimal error producing example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib as mpl
# Bad character pasted into vim from chrome: –
```

To fix just remove the "EN DASH" (or the entire line 3) and the matplotlib imports correctly.

So why does the invalid(?) unicode in the comments cause an error only when trying to `import matplotlib`(and before it even reaches the comment in question)

```
python==3.5.2

colorama==0.3.7
comtypes==1.1.2
cycler==0.10.0
matplotlib==1.5.1
numpy==1.11.1
pandas==0.18.1
py==1.4.31
pyparsing==2.1.4
pytest==2.9.2
python-dateutil==2.5.3
pytz==2016.6.1
pywin32==220
scikit-learn==0.17.1
scipy==0.18.0
six==1.10.0
```

Comment: Looking at this code in pyparsing, the issue arises when trying to see if a potential exception would be raised in caller code or in pyparsing code.I have checked in a proposed fix to SVN this morning that limits the levels of call stack that pyparsing retrieves when making this determination - please download it and try it out. (I'm updating my unit tests of course, but not sure I can reproduce this specific error case.)

Comment: pyparsing 2.1.8 was just pushed to PyPI - please do `pip install -U pyparsing` to get the latest version, and retry your script.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Just did a straight up comparison and I can confirm that that update fixes my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in [pyparsing](http://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/):

> The pyparsing module is an alternative approach to creating and executing simple grammars, vs. the traditional lex/yacc approach, or the use of regular expressions. With pyparsing, you don't need to learn a new syntax for defining grammars or matching expressions - the parsing module provides a library of classes that you use to construct the grammar directly in Python.

In order to "construct the grammar directly in Python", pyparsing needs to read the source file (in this case a matplotlib source file) where the grammar is defined. In what would usually just be a bit of harmless extra work, pyparsing is reading not just the matplotlib source file but everything in the stack at the point the grammar is defined, all the way down to the source file where you have your `import matplotlib`. When it reaches your source file it chokes, because your file indeed is not in UTF-8; 0x96 is the Windows-1252 (and/or Latin-1) encoding for the en dash. This issue (reading too much of the stack) has [already been fixed](https://sourceforge.net/p/pyparsing/code/415/) by [the author of pyparsing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165216/paul-mcguire) so the fix should be in the next [release of pyparsing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyparsing) (probably 2.1.8).

By the way, matplotlib is defining a pyparsing grammar in order to be able to read fontconfig files, which are a way of configuring fonts used mainly on Linux. So on Windows pyparsing is probably not even required to use matplotlib!

Comment: "lazy" might be a little judgmental - at this place in pyparsing, I'm actually jumping through some extra hoops, trying to minimize the work required by the caller code. I'm hoping that by adding `limit=n` args to calls to `extract_stack` and `extract_tb`, I can mitigate this problem. (The underlying issue is that, in calling a user callback, pyparsing may raise a TypeError internally, and the exception itself is not distinguishable from a TypeError that might be raised in the user's callback code - hence the need to inspect the call stack.)

Comment: @PaulMcGuire sorry, that was indeed out of line and I'll reword it. Thanks for working on pyparsing and for quickly fixing this issue.

Comment: Thanks, and no hard feelings. As for matplotlib's use of pyparsing, I know that at least at one time, pyparsing was used in the mathtext module, but I couldn't say if that was still the case.

Comment: Windows-1252 is not Latin-1. They do share lots of codepoints but not all. Confusing "about the same" (human view) and "exactly the same" (computer needs) is the root of many crashes (such as this one).